# At what time of day does US visa expire?

Tags: visas, usa, visa-expiration

My visa expires on Nov 13th 2014. Does that mean its valid until 13th midnight or 12th midnight?

Comment: @pnuts Thanks for the comment. Any official doc to support this?

Answer (score 6):

If your visa is valid until a date, that includes that date.

Don't worry, this is an extremely common question, common enough that there's a whole page on it on the [US travel site](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/general/visa-expiration-date.html).

However, remember, as pointed out there - that your visa validity isn't necessarily how long you're authorised to stay in the US - the CBP at port of entry could determine that despite having a visa that expires in 3 months that you only need two weeks, and will stamp as such.  Example, I flew into Boston for 2 weeks of travel - instead of being given the 90 days that NZers can get visa free, he just gave me enough time to complete my trip, and stamped accordingly.